# How can I exclude a specific value when echoing from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I'm making a page were I pull in job postings.  Basically, I'm pulling the job info from one file using PHP.  When there are no jobs to be posted I want the div and it's header text to not appear on the page. Which I got to work, my problem is that I have to leave one file in the folder so that I can keep a job template in there so I can copy/paste it when a new job comes in without having to type it out every time. But with that one file in the folder it wants to post a job to the page.  I need it to ignore this one file and not display it (The files title is "Template.php").

How do I make it so if there is only the "Template.php" file in the "positions.php" it does not display on the webpage?

Right now I'm using:

```
if (count($folder) === 1) {
    echo '';
}
else {
    echo '<h2 class="job-category">Job Position</h2>';
}
```

But that is only for the div containing my H2 text, not the whole div and I want to specifically be able to exclude the "Template.php" file:

```
$folder = (glob("positions/*.php")) ;

    if (count($folder) === 1) {
        echo '';
    }
    else {
        echo '<h2 class="job-category">Job Position</h2>';
    }

    foreach(array_chunk($folder , 1 ,true)as $filename) 
    {
        echo '<div class="job-posting">' ;
        foreach ($filename as $position)

            include $position;
        }
    echo '</div>';  
    }
```

Comment: Why not put the template in a different directory or not on your site at all? Seems odd to have a template like this, which is used for convenience in authoring be part of the actual site structure.  Why are you using `array_chunk()` there in your loop definition?  Considering that you are using a chunk size of 1, you are doing nothing but adding another level of depth to your array structure for no apparent reason.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could use `array_filter` to remove `Template.php` from `$folder` before you check the count.

Comment: @MikeBrant I was needing the Template to be on the site since the files will be edited by a third party using FlatCMS (http://www.flatcms.nl/)  I was using array_chunk because as far as I've understood it, it would keep each value in the array separate so I could post them individually.  Thanks for pointing these out! This is the first time I've tried  php on a project, I just started trying to understand it this morning.

Comment: @CALEBUNGA That still doesn't indicate why the file needs to be in the directory you are interested in or the site at all.  There are plenty of ways to get a template to a third party including email, revision control tools (like Git)), etc.  Why put cruft in your application?

Comment: Perfect! I'll look into doing that instead! thanks! @MikeBrant